# How can I modify zsh to autocomplete `source` with the local directory before the $PATH?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh, zsh-completion

I can't count the number of times I've typed: `source en<tab>` only to be left with a bunch of garbled text on the screen because it sourced the program env instead of the local env.sh.

I tried making a simple function to detect this particular use case but it didn't work.

This is what I tried:

```
source () {
    if [ "$1" == "env" ]
    then
        source ./env.sh
    else
        source $@
    fi
}
```

I realize that source is a shell command which is probably why it didn't work but I don't really care about how its implemented, I just want to stop sourcing binaries on my $PATH before the local directory.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is that you're calling your function recursively. Use `builtin source` to call the builtin source rather than your function source:

```
source () {
    if [ "$1" == "env" ]
    then
        builtin source ./env.sh
    else
        builtin source $@
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than override a general command (`source`) to handle a special case, make
a new command to handle the special case.

```
locenv () {
    source ./env.sh
}
```